# Where is the schema designer in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xsd

I remember running into this problem last year, and I solved it by working with Visual Studio 2005.

Does VS 2008 not have an xsd designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't released until [VS2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/downloads/default.mspx), so it might not be in your version, but you should be able to download it.

Comment: But wow, its terrible.  Sticking with 2005.